# Session fixation when bean is defined in session scope in jsf facesConfig.xml;

Tags: session, jsf

In my application I have session fixation issues.
I have done the fix in the following way:
1. request.getsession(false);
2. session.invalidate();
3. request.getsession(true);
I am able to create a new session after successful login. But the problem is that in facesConfig.xml there are some beans which are defined in session scope. So, what happen whenever I  invalidate() the session the bean getting null. 
The question is how can I set the bean after invalidating the session?

Comment: Just send a redirect after invalidate/login to start afresh?

Comment: If i make a redirect it will again point to login page.which I dont want. I want to recreate the session and set the bean in the new session.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong. It should not end up in login page. Your current attempt just causes the problem you described in the question.

Comment: in facesConfig.xml bean scope is in session if made the scope application.Then it works good. But dont want to change the scope and want to set the bean again after the session is invalidated.